# OneSignal - Certificate revoked or not valid on APNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, onesignal

I am trying to renew the certificate for OneSignal that my app uses for iOS.

I have followed the instructions of OneSignal here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate#21-request-a-certificate-from-a-certificate-authority

Problem is: I tried both the manual method with the KeyChain and the automatic method using the "[OneSignal's Provisionator Tool](https://onesignal.com/provisionator)" but when I download the .p12 file in OneSignal settings page, I get the same error:

Certificate revoked or not valid on APNS

[image: Error when uploading new .p12 file]

It is probably something silly (sorry if it is) but has anyone seen this before and do you have any suggestion on how to solve this? Now that I followed the automated method, my current certificate was revoked so I broke the push notification service of my app on iOS :/

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

The solution from OneSignal support was: rename the .p12 file and try again. It worked. It seems to be related to the plugin they use to upload files on the website.